# formik form reset after form submit react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using Formik for my react form. After form submit, I need to reset form. I need to reset form inside the save function. This is my save function.

```
  const saveForm= (event) => {
    const header = {
      Auth_token: `${appUserConfig.accessTokenName}=${appUserConfig.accessToken}`,
      User_name: appUserConfig.userName,
    };
    console.log(data);
    httpPost(SAVE_INVOICE,data, header)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          toast.success('Successfully Saved', {position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT})
        }
       resetForm();
       // I need to call reset function here 
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        toast.error('Error', {position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT})
        console.log("e:", e);
      });
}
```

I followed Formik Documentation. According to there doc below code is work for me.

```
    <Formik
    initialValues={!location.state ? InvoiceInitalValues : location.state}
    validationSchema={POValidation}
    onSubmit={(form, actions, resetForm ) => {
      console.log(form);
      setTimeout(() => {
        saveInvoice(form);
        actions.setSubmitting(false);
        actions.resetForm();
      }, 1000);
    }}
  >
```

But I need to reset form inside the save function. How i reset my form inside the save function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can approach this, one would be to call your saveForm inside onSubmit function of Formik component and pass the parameter which handle to your saveForm which handles the reset event.
Example

```
 onSubmit:{(form, actions, resetForm ) => {
      saveForm(form, actions);
 }}

   const saveForm = (form, { resetForm }) => {
        //save form code
       resetForm();
    }
```

or You can directly set it to the onSubmit function like this

```
onSubmit:saveForm
```

This will directly pass all the parameter that onSubmit is recieving to your saveForm function.

Comment: I added this to my function
 onSubmit:{(form, actions, resetForm ) => {
      saveForm(form, actions);
 }}

error said , 'resetForm' of 'undefined'

Comment: const component = () => {

  const saveForm = (values, formHelper) => {
    ///save form code
    formHelper.resetForm()
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik initialValues={{ abc:"" }} onSubmit={(values,formikHelper)=>{
        saveForm(values, formikHelper);
      }}>

      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

Comment: try this snippet